# What is the collection for?

Tags: professor-layton-the-last-specter

I keep randomly finding various items, such as Bad Art or a Hair Clip that get added to the Collection in layton's trunk.

Does collecting all of these hidden items get me anything? Knowing Professor Layton games, I suspect that they might, but I could be wrong.

Comment: As a side note, you know those mouse badges? They unlock the Mouse Alley minigame: http://professorlayton4walkthrough.blogspot.com/2011/10/mousealley.html

Comment: @Krazer Thanks for the link! I was wondering about those too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From everything I've seen/read, there is no benefit to collecting all of these items, save for that feeling of personal satisfaction that you might get.

Here's a list of all of the items and their locations: http://layton.wikia.com/wiki/Collection. There is no mention about some kind of reward that is unlocked after collecting them all. But if you do find all of them and it does in fact give you something, please let me know.